# PySQLPool and Celery, proper way to use it?

Tags: python, mysql, multiprocessing, celery, connection-pooling

I am wondering what is the proper way to use the mysql pool with celery tasks.
At the moment, this is how (the relevant portion) of my tasks module looks like:

```
from start import celery
import PySQLPool as pool

dbcfg = config.get_config('inputdb')
input_db = pool.getNewConnection(username=dbcfg['user'], password=dbcfg['passwd'], host=dbcfg['host'], port=dbcfg['port'], db=dbcfg['db'], charset='utf8')

dbcfg = config.get_config('outputdb')
output_db = pool.getNewConnection(username=dbcfg['user'], password=dbcfg['passwd'], host=dbcfg['host'], port=dbcfg['port'], db=dbcfg['db'], charset='utf8')

@celery.task
def fetch():
   ic = pool.getNewQuery(input_db)
   oc = pool.getNewQuery(output_db)

   count = 1
   for e in get_new_stuff():
      # do stuff with new stuff
      # read the db with ic
      # write to db using oc

      # commit from time to time
      if count % 1000:
         pool.commitPool()

   # commit whatever's left
   pool.commitPool()
```

On one machine there can be at most 4 fetch() tasks running at the same time (1 per core).
I notice, however, that sometimes a task will hang and I suspect it is due to mysql.
Any tips on how to use mysql and celery?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am also using celery and PySQLPool.

```
maria = PySQLPool.getNewConnection(username=app.config["MYSQL_USER"],
                                   password=app.config["MYSQL_PASSWORD"],
                                   host=app.config["MYSQL_HOST"],
                                   db='configuration')

def myfunc(self, param1, param2):

    query = PySQLPool.getNewQuery(maria, True)
    try:
        sSql = """
            SELECT * FROM table
            WHERE col1= %s AND col2 
            """
        tDatas = ( var1, var2)
        query.Query(sSql, tDatas)
        return query.record
    except Exception, e:
        logger.info(e)
        return False

@celery.task
def fetch():
    myfunc('hello', 'world')
```